# Populate a textarea in a webpage from excel using VBA and Fetch error message into the excel columns

Tags: excel, vba, automated-tests

Hi I'm new here and also new to VBA I want to automate a process
I want to fetch an excel sheet 1 column A value one by one and check whether it shows an error or not by fetching the error message into column B according to the values fetched. I have been trying it to work in chrome also every time the page gets reloaded so the element id is changing so I cant populate the text area. Any suggestions are helpful
Let me clear the process in a simple way

1. Excel Sheet 1 Column A has values from 1 to 10
2. The value from A1 must be fetched and entered into the text area
3. If the value shows an error, the error msg must be fetched into column B1
   The div class="sc-eLgOdN blnocm" is where the error shows
4. If no Error leaves the column empty.
5. after fetching the error msg into B1 the value from A2 must be fetched to the website
   textarea and check for error

I want to populate and check error for the values in the column A1 to A10

here is the CSS of the form

```html
    <div class="tp- ghdtsj hadsiHS">

<label for="id-KJNHKShsishd" 
data-testid="label" 
class="tp- sdjbnlsdnkd">Data</label>

<div class="tp- sdjkbsjKHKJ JKnh">

<textarea placeholder="Paste your Name Data here" 
data-testid="native-input" 
id="id-BHSsdhgaiJHG zmnccJ"   '''{The id is changing every time on page reload}'''
class="sc-hRxedE fUNANR">
</textarea>

</div>
</div>
<div class="tp- BSjkhK KJHjhskja"></div>   '''{This where the error message shows}'''
```

Comment: It should be work with a querySelector (untested): `document.querySelector("textarea[data-testid="native-input"]")` More about querySelectors https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll For more help we need your VBA code and if possible the original URL to the page.

Comment: Hi as it is my company website it needs login details to access the page so I can't specifically give the url of the webpage as it's confidential as per your suggestion I used the query selector the webpage is opening but the value is not been entered into the text box

Answer (score 0):

Hi zwenn thanks for the reply the website is my company's login data verification page it needs to login username and pass to open the page as I tried by query selector nothing happens here is the VBA code I'm trying to achieve
Sub pullDataFromWeb()

Dim IE As Object
Shell("chromepath -url the page URL")
IE.Visible = True

Do While IE.Busy Or ReadySate <> 4
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

IE.document.querySelector("textarea[data-testid='native-input']").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table_1").Range("A2").Value it doesn't work.

End Sub